# Capture and delete matching original order and cancelled order using pandas/python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

My dataset is a sales transactions history of an online store consists of 541000+ records. The head looks like this:

```
   InvoiceNo StockCode                          Description  Quantity          InvoiceDate  UnitPrice  CustomerID  TotalSales
0     536365    85123A   WHITE HANGING HEART T-LIGHT HOLDER         6  2018-11-29 08:26:00       2.55       17850       15.30
1     536365     71053                  WHITE METAL LANTERN         6  2018-11-29 08:26:00       3.39       17850       20.34
2     536365    84406B       CREAM CUPID HEARTS COAT HANGER         8  2018-11-29 08:26:00       2.75       17850       22.00
3     536365    84029G  KNITTED UNION FLAG HOT WATER BOTTLE         6  2018-11-29 08:26:00       3.39       17850       20.34
4     536365    84029E       RED WOOLLY HOTTIE WHITE HEART.         6  2018-11-29 08:26:00       3.39       17850       20.34
```

Upon data exploration, I found out that there are cancelled invoices with matching original invoice, but the `original InvoiceNo` and `cancelled InvoiceNo` are not the same. Cancelled invoices are indicated by `InvoiceNo` starting with `C`.

```
  InvoiceNo  StockCode                     Description  Quantity          InvoiceDate  UnitPrice  CustomerID  TotalSales
0    541431      23166  MEDIUM CERAMIC TOP STORAGE JAR     74215  2019-01-16 10:01:00       1.04       12346     77183.6
1   C541433      23166  MEDIUM CERAMIC TOP STORAGE JAR    -74215  2019-01-16 10:17:00       1.04       12346    -77183.6
2    581483      23843     PAPER CRAFT , LITTLE BIRDIE     80995  2019-12-07 09:15:00       2.08       16446    168469.6
3   C581484      23843     PAPER CRAFT , LITTLE BIRDIE    -80995  2019-12-07 09:27:00       2.08       16446   -168469.6
```

Now before I perform any analysis, I want to remove those invoices that are cancelled, meaning both the original invoice and its corresponding cancelled invoice.

Since the `cancellation InvoiceNo` is not the same `InvoiceNo` as the original order, and due to the limitation of my dataset, the only way to find the matching order and cancelled order that I can think of, is to generate records were the columns `StockCode, Description, UnitPrice, CustomerID and absolute Quantity` are duplicated. Some orders are cancelled after a few days so `InvoiceDate` is not included. However when I run the code below, it returns 244747 records.

```py
df2 = df_clean[df_clean.duplicated(['StockCode', 'Description', 'UnitPrice', 
                                               'CustomerID', 'Quantity_ABS'], keep=False)]
```

The reason is that, each invoice could contain multiple lines of StockCode and a customer orders the same StockCode with the same quantity across the coverage of the dataset. There are only 3679 cancellation invoices so that means the original invoice matching the cancelled invoice should also be about the same number.

Now I sorted my df2 by `CustomerID` then by `StockCode`, then by `Quantity` and set `inplace=True` for easy tracking and viewing.

```py
df2.sort_values(by=['CustomerID', 'StockCode', 'Quantity'], inplace=True)
```

What I want to do is for every `customerID`, delete only the records that has a cancelled invoice (InvoiceNo that starts with C) as well as the matching order.

For example, this how it shows if I display all the records for CustomerID 15749:

```py
df2[df2['CustomerID'] == '15749']
```

```
  InvoiceNo StockCode                         Description  Quantity          InvoiceDate  UnitPrice  CustomerID  TotalSales
0   C550456     21108  FAIRY CAKE FLANNEL ASSORTED COLOUR     -3114  2019-04-16 13:08:00       2.10       15749     -6539.4
1    540815     21108  FAIRY CAKE FLANNEL ASSORTED COLOUR      3114  2019-01-09 12:55:00       2.10       15749      6539.4
2    550461     21108  FAIRY CAKE FLANNEL ASSORTED COLOUR      3114  2019-04-16 13:20:00       2.10       15749      6539.4
3   C550456     21175         GIN + TONIC DIET METAL SIGN     -2000  2019-04-16 13:08:00       1.85       15749     -3700.0
4    540815     21175         GIN + TONIC DIET METAL SIGN      2000  2019-01-09 12:55:00       1.85       15749      3700.0
5   C550456     48185                  DOORMAT FAIRY CAKE      -670  2019-04-16 13:08:00       6.75       15749     -4522.5
6    540818     48185                  DOORMAT FAIRY CAKE       670  2019-01-09 12:57:00       6.75       15749      4522.5
7   C550456    85123A  WHITE HANGING HEART T-LIGHT HOLDER     -1930  2019-04-16 13:08:00       2.55       15749     -4921.5
8    540815    85123A  WHITE HANGING HEART T-LIGHT HOLDER      1930  2019-01-09 12:55:00       2.55       15749      4921.5
```

So here, I want to delete the records in pairs: the `InvoiceNo` that starts with `C` and the corresponding original invoice because they offset each other. But InvoiceNo `550461` will remain as it is a valid sale (or not cancelled).

Another example CustomerID `16013`:

```
  InvoiceNo StockCode                         Description  Quantity          InvoiceDate  UnitPrice  CustomerID  TotalSales
0   C539329     20733              GOLD MINI TAPE MEASURE      -300  2018-12-15 09:37:00       0.72       16013      -216.0
1    539109     20733              GOLD MINI TAPE MEASURE       300  2018-12-14 11:07:00       0.72       16013       216.0
2    539331     20733              GOLD MINI TAPE MEASURE       300  2018-12-15 09:39:00       0.72       16013       216.0
3    546521     21471        STRAWBERRY RAFFIA FOOD COVER        48  2019-03-12 12:34:00       2.95       16013       141.6
4    551618     21471        STRAWBERRY RAFFIA FOOD COVER        48  2019-05-01 11:42:00       2.95       16013       141.6
5    580763     79321                       CHILLI LIGHTS        96  2019-12-04 10:36:00       4.95       16013       475.2
6   C539329    85123A  WHITE HANGING HEART T-LIGHT HOLDER      -500  2018-12-15 09:37:00       2.55       16013     -1275.0
7    543675    85123A  WHITE HANGING HEART T-LIGHT HOLDER       150  2019-02-09 11:31:00       2.55       16013       382.5
8    555075    85123A  WHITE HANGING HEART T-LIGHT HOLDER       150  2019-05-29 12:05:00       2.55       16013       382.5
9    539109    85123A  WHITE HANGING HEART T-LIGHT HOLDER       500  2018-12-14 11:07:00       2.55       16013      1275.0
```

Here, only Invoice `C539329/539109` with index 0 and 1 and `C539329/539109` with index 6 and 9 will be deleted.

I can't seem to figure out how to do this programmatically and efficiently. Although I can do this manually in Excel, it will take too much time and is not allowed for the project.

Please advise if this can be done in python and how. Also if you have any other ideas on how to solve this other than what I have already done, please advise. It is highly appeciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what if have four rows with all matching values. 
`
C539329
539109
539110
C539330

`

As per your conditions the invoice starting with C should be deleted. Index 0 and 3 are gone. Which you want to keep 1 or 2 ?

Comment: Yes, all invoices that starts with C should be deleted. But the corresponding original invoice should also be deleted. And that is what I am trying to find out - how to filter those cancelled invoices as well as the corresponding invoices so I can delete them together (or in pairs).

Comment: Can we safely assume that you want to keep the last one (which does not start with C and all the necessary columns match) ?

Comment: Yes, I want to keep the last one without C since those orders were placed after the cancellation

Comment: Sorry for back to back questions . There are multiple cases here. In your last example for customer -`16013` - index 3 and 4 has the same values. Ideally index 3 should be deleted. But we need to take into account only if the group has cancelled orders. Since index 3 and 4 doesn't have any invoices starting with 'C', it hasn't been considered. am I correct ?

Comment: No Sorry, I appreciate that you're trying to understand my problem. Yes index 3 and 4 should not be considered for deletion because there is no corresponding cancelled invoice.

Comment: Thanks. but it contradicts your statement - `Here, only Invoice C539329/539109 with index 0 and 1 and C539329/539109 with index 6 and 9 will be deleted.` . 

Index 6 is `C539329` and index 9 is `539109` . If you wish to keep the last one, index 6 should be dropped and index 9 should be preserved.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question as rules. it would be easy to understand.. something like, 

what happens when there are two rows when 1 with 'C' and other without C
When there are 3 or more rows, where there is 1 'C' , followed by many non 'C's

When if there are 4 rows where - 1st one is 'C; and second is non 'C', 3rd one is 'C' and 4th one is non 'C'.

There are many cases like this.. Can you please think and edit your question. it would really help to design the logic and provide appropriate answer.

Comment: Sorry if it creates confusion. I will try to make it simpler. So, for every cancelled invoice, I want to find the corresponding original invoice then delete them both.  I tried locating those by generating the records where the the columns StockCode, Description, UnitPrice, CustomerID and absolute Quantity are duplicated. But it gave me a long list. Then I sorted by CustomerID, then by StockCode then by absolute Quantity. But still I can't figure out how to filter those pairs (cancelled invoice and its matching original invoice). Hope I explained it better?

Comment: Is there ever a legitimate reason for having a negative `Quantity` or `TotalSales` (Besides Cancelations)?

Comment: HI @BeRT2me - it's only for cancellations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given:

```
  InvoiceNo  StockCode                        Description  Quantity          InvoiceDate  UnitPrice  CustomerID  TotalSales
0   C539329     20733              GOLD MINI TAPE MEASURE      -300  2018-12-15 09:37:00       0.72       16013      -216.0
1    539109     20733              GOLD MINI TAPE MEASURE       300  2018-12-14 11:07:00       0.72       16013       216.0
2    539331     20733              GOLD MINI TAPE MEASURE       300  2018-12-15 09:39:00       0.72       16013       216.0
3    546521     21471        STRAWBERRY RAFFIA FOOD COVER        48  2019-03-12 12:34:00       2.95       16013       141.6
4    551618     21471        STRAWBERRY RAFFIA FOOD COVER        48  2019-05-01 11:42:00       2.95       16013       141.6
5    580763     79321                       CHILLI LIGHTS        96  2019-12-04 10:36:00       4.95       16013       475.2
6   C539329    85123A  WHITE HANGING HEART T-LIGHT HOLDER      -500  2018-12-15 09:37:00       2.55       16013     -1275.0
7    543675    85123A  WHITE HANGING HEART T-LIGHT HOLDER       150  2019-02-09 11:31:00       2.55       16013       382.5
8    555075    85123A  WHITE HANGING HEART T-LIGHT HOLDER       150  2019-05-29 12:05:00       2.55       16013       382.5
9    539109    85123A  WHITE HANGING HEART T-LIGHT HOLDER       500  2018-12-14 11:07:00       2.55       16013      1275.0
```

This is just one method, I'm sure there are others, and there may be some flaws with this one.

```
# Mark your cancellation columns:
mask = df.InvoiceNo.str.startswith('C')

# Make a copy of your cancellation columns:
op_df = df[mask].copy()

# Inverse Quantity and TotalSales:
cols = ['Quantity', 'TotalSales']
op_df[cols] = op_df[cols].mul(-1)

# Get rid of these cols:
drop_cols = ['InvoiceNo', 'InvoiceDate']
op_df = op_df.drop(columns=drop_cols)

# What are left?
op_cols = op_df.columns.tolist()

# Drop all the cancellation columns:
df = df[~mask]

# Make a new mask, this is all the columns that match a cancelation column:
mask = (df.drop(columns=drop_cols)
          .apply(lambda x: op_df.isin(x.values).all(axis=1).any(), axis=1))

# There are two categories we want to drop, both start with:
groups = df[mask].sort_values('InvoiceDate').groupby(op_cols)
dropme = [] # List of indices to drop~
# 1. Where there's only one match, add them to the drop list.
dropme.extend(groups.filter(lambda x: len(x)==1)
                    .index
                    .tolist())
# 2. Where there are multiple matches, Add the oldest to the drop list.
dropme.extend(groups.filter(lambda x: len(x)>1)
                    .sort_values('InvoiceDate')
                    .drop_duplicates(op_cols, keep='first')
                    .index
                    .tolist())

# Drop them!
df = df.drop(dropme)
print(df)
```

Output:

- `0, 1, 6, 9` have all been removed.

```
  InvoiceNo StockCode                         Description  Quantity          InvoiceDate  UnitPrice  CustomerID  TotalSales
2    539331     20733              GOLD MINI TAPE MEASURE       300  2018-12-15 09:39:00       0.72       16013       216.0
3    546521     21471        STRAWBERRY RAFFIA FOOD COVER        48  2019-03-12 12:34:00       2.95       16013       141.6
4    551618     21471        STRAWBERRY RAFFIA FOOD COVER        48  2019-05-01 11:42:00       2.95       16013       141.6
5    580763     79321                       CHILLI LIGHTS        96  2019-12-04 10:36:00       4.95       16013       475.2
7    543675    85123A  WHITE HANGING HEART T-LIGHT HOLDER       150  2019-02-09 11:31:00       2.55       16013       382.5
8    555075    85123A  WHITE HANGING HEART T-LIGHT HOLDER       150  2019-05-29 12:05:00       2.55       16013       382.5
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried your solution in a smaller dataset and it worked!